# how to render only recently added object of my model in my template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

how to show only recently added object of my model instead of all in my template here is my views.py

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        quote = Quote.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'qoutes':quote})
```

right now if render the object all the quote will shown to me but instead of all the model i want to render only recent quote which i added got render

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    todays_Quote = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.todays_Quote
```

Comment: When is a `Quote` considered recent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the last 10 `Quote`s with:

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        quote = Quote.objects.order_by('-created')[:10]
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'qoutes':quote})
```

or we can retrieve all `Quote`s submitted for example the last day with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import now

class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
        quote = Quote.objects.filter(created__gte=Now()-timedelta(days=1))
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'qoutes':quote})
```